# Using VB .net to click command button in Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to click a button in a form in MS Access with VB .net. However, there isn't much I can find in this area and have a bit of a long way of getting the button. Then I'm stuck - there seems to be no way to activate the click event.

Using :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

I have the following to get the button:

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\path\to\db\aDatabase.accdb")
acc.Visible = True
For i = 0 To acc.Forms.Count - 1
    If acc.Forms.Item(i).Name = "formName" Then
        For j = 0 To acc.Forms.Item(i).Controls.Count - 1
            If acc.Forms.Item(i).Controls.Item(j).name = "btnEnter" Then
                Dim btn As Access.CommandButton = acc.Forms.Item(i).Controls.Item(j)
                '
                ' click on button??
                '
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

I've had a guess at trying the following:

```
acc.Application.Run(btn.OnClickMacro)
acc.Application.Run(btn.OnClick)
btn.OnClickMacro
btn.OnClick
btn.performclick()
```

none of which work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the click event handler is declared in VBA as

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    ' do something
End Sub
```

You won't be able to programmatically click the button outside of Access' VBA code if it's private (unless the developer intentionally declared it public). Best practice is to make a function which is called by the handler, which can be called elsewhere as well, instead of clicking buttons through code.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoSomething
End Sub

' you would have a better chance calling this from .NET
Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' do something
End Sub
```

If you don't have access to the Access VBA code, outside of .NET you could use something to automate mouse clicks like this: https://autohotkey.com/

Comment: Yes, but I would like to avoid external programs and click on a button with a private sub. If I can reference the button, surely there must be a way to fire the event.

Comment: Try `acc.Run("formName!Command0_Click")` or variant, from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/68143-call-private-sub-different-module.html

Comment: nope - tried a number of varieties and it raises the error that it can't find it

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you have to have Access intslled, open and running, then why is such code not being run from Access? So it does not make a whole lot of sense to call such code from .net.
However, simply make the private sub click as public, and then you can use this form:

```
MyAccessApp.Forms("main").command44_click
```

So you don’t have to create any external functions etc., but if you wish to call that code directly then the form MUST be opened, and with a running instance of that application from .net, then the above syntax will work.

I would suggest you just use Access here, and it nots clear why .net is involved.